# Using the football-data api with Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, api

I'm trying to make a successful api call to the football-data api using Angular. Here's the documentation: http://www.football-data.org/documentation

Using the sample code in the documentation, I have managed to get JSON data back using jQuery, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': 'YOUR_API_TOKEN' },
  url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/fixtures?timeFrame=n1',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'GET',
}).done(function(response) {
  // do something with the response, e.g. isolate the id of a linked resource        
  var regex = /.*?(\d+)$/; // the ? makes the first part non-greedy
  var res = regex.exec(response.fixtures[0]._links.awayTeam.href);
  var teamId = res[1];
  console.log(teamId);
});
```

But being relatively new to Angular, I'm unsure how to do the same thing in that environment. Going through some tutorials, I have setup an `service` that uses `HTTP` to `map` a response from the url to JSON like so:

```
export class FootballService {
  private _url: string = "http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426/leagueTable";
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getLeagueTable(){
    return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

And I have imported this service on to my component like this:

```
export class ApiComponent implements OnInit {
  table = [];
  constructor(private _footyService: FootballService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._footyService.getLeagueTable()
      .subscribe(res => this.table = res);
  }

}
```

But there's clearly issues in my code that I can't identify, as I'm not getting any valid JSON through this. I'd appreciate if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the angular tutorial for http client. especially the `headers` section: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#headers

you need to use the http service as follows:

first look at the api for `Http`: https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html

`get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable<Response>`

the `RequestOptionsArgs` api: https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptionsArgs-interface.html

```
interface RequestOptionsArgs {
  url : string
  method : string|RequestMethod
  search : string|URLSearchParams
  headers : Headers
  body : any
  withCredentials : boolean
  responseType : ResponseContentType
}
```

so you can use:

```
    let headers = new Headers({ 'X-Auth-Token': 'YOUR_API_TOKEN' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.http.get('URL HERE', options).subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get 'YOUR_API_TOKEN' from the service provider and pass it in headers

```
 headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': 'YOUR_API_TOKEN' }
```

like

```
this._http.get(this._url, 
   new RequestOptions({headers: {'X-Auth-Token': 'YOUR_API_TOKEN'}}));
```

Comment: I already have the API key. My question is, where in the code should the `headers` go?

Answer (score 0):

let dive into **01-08-2019 solution** :

imports :

```
import {Http,Headers} from '@angular/http';
```

then you need to declare object of type headers like this :

```
  headers = new Headers();
  url1;
```

after that you have to append this to the headers variable **inside the constructor**  :

```
this.headers.append('X-RapidAPI-Key', 'c7ea217786msh32_Rest of your token_83fjsn7f8b8fe644f0');
this.url1 = 'https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/leagueTable/2';
```

the last step is to fill your get **method** like this :

```
   getStandings() {

       // tslint:disable-next-line: deprecation
       return this.http.get(this.url1 ,  {headers: this.headers}).pipe(
       map(res => res.json())
       );


   }
```

that's all you need to make your token works fine without problem .